# Azure Media player gives "no compatible source was found for this media 0x10600000" error on android

Tags: azure, media, mpeg

Azure Media player gives "no compatible source was found for this media 0x10600000" error on android for downloaded video files for few formats like mpeg. Http url for the same file is playing fine but, if we download the file to local storage and try to play from storage it throws this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be related to the **Media Server** being able to do different encodings/formats to match the players supported formats, but once a file is downloaded locally, if the player doesn't support the format internally, it won't be able to play it.

I would suggest you try to tweak the encoding/format using **HTTP** headers (I think it's the `Accepts` header) and to trigger a download with a format supported by the player.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Itay. The video files are from our own source and only one format of each file is available, so cannot trigger for supported format. May be I need to convert the format of the downloaded file using some tool.